# jQuery mouseenter/leave not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iFrame in my page and in my iFrame I have 2 divs that I want to alternate when it comes to which one is being displayed.

I'd like to set it up s.t. when the mouse is hovered over (or just enters) the iFrame I show the `<div>` with `id='note'` and when the mouse leaves the iFrame, I want to show the `<div>` with `id='preview'` but my jQuery listener isn't behaving as I'd like. Here's my js code,

```
function showNotePreview(showPreview){
    console.log('mouse action detected with show prev of', showPreview);
    if (showPreview){
        $('#preview').removeClass('collapse');
        $('#note').addClass('collapse');
    }else{
        $('#note').removeClass('collapse');
        $('#preview').addClass('collapse');
    }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    // debugger;
    $('html,body').mouseover(showNotePreview(true));
    $('html,body').mouseout(showNotePreview(false));
});
```

This is my html,

```
       <textarea id="note" class="note" name="note_content"></textarea>
       <div class="collapse" id="preview">hi im a preview...</div>
```

When the page first loads and I step through the mouseover & mouseenter lines being executed (in chrome) I see the callback functions automatically executed but there is no lasting 'listening' effect by the listeners as  I mouse over and out of the iframe..

This is the log when the iframe loads up,

```
mouse action detected with show prev of true
mouse action detected with show prev of false
```

Is there something I'm missing about mouseover/enter/hover/leave/etc ? Maybe some iFrame caveat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are executing straight away. You need to pass to `mouseover()` and `mouseout()` the function that will be executed when the events fire instead of executing them yourself.

Bind the event handlers using:

```
$('html,body').mouseover(function(){ showNotePreview(true); });
$('html,body').mouseout(function(){ showNotePreview(false); });
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b19hq5d/)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look at the jQuery version of this, but you can do it with just CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/w6qjfvzq/

Edit: Daniel has told you why your jQuery doesn't work. He's spot on. I'll keep this here, because CSS is a better solution for this (less load on the browser).

```css
#preview {
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
}
#editor {
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
}

html:hover #preview {
    display: none;
}
html:hover #editor {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">Some content</div>
<textarea id="editor">Some content</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! I wish I could accept both answers. I am definitely using this css approach as it also involves less js spaghetti. I did need to know why my jQuery wasn't working so that now I can do other actions when the mouse leaves the frame.